# How do I load a text file into dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, readfile

I have some text files with a format like this

```
{"key":"value", "key":"value", "key":"value"}

{"key":"value", "key":"value", "key":"value"}
```

There's a new line character after every string. Basically it has multiple dictionaries and I want to read some specific values from them one by one.

Comment: OK, so what have you tried and what's the problem with it? SO is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate. Here is the answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4917044/2930045

Comment: @DuckPuncher That's for a JSON file, the question is about a regular file. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803999/python-file-to-dictionary for that.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `ast.literal_eval`

```
with open("your_file.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        my_dict = ast.literal_eval(line.strip())
        # play wiht you dict here now
```

Demo:

```
>>> mystr = '{"a":1, "b":2}\n'
>>> k = ast.literal_eval(mystr.strip())
>>> k
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> type(k)
<type 'dict'>
>>> k['a']
1
```