# Unpack Python URL Request

Tags: python, dictionary, python-requests

I'm using:

```
import requests

data = 'text=great'

print(requests.post('http://text-processing.com/api/sentiment/', data=data).text)
```

which returns:

```
{"probability": {"neg": 0.30135019761690551, "neutral": 0.27119050546800266, "pos": 0.69864980238309449}, "label": "pos"}
```

and I want to browse that using the structure not just as a string of text. How can I turn it into a dictionary?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917006/string-to-dictionary-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`json()` method](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content) which would load the JSON response content and return you a Python data structure:

```
response = requests.post('http://text-processing.com/api/sentiment/', data=data)
print(response.json())
```