# how to split my string into a nested dict with delimiter exceptions?

Tags: python, dictionary, delimiter

I need to use `.split` to split a string and make a nested dictionary, and have used `','` however, as can be seen in my data below, `,` shows up several times in the 'Reviewed' field, causing Python to label values as keys incorrectly. The Review field is meant to be a list within the dict.

A sample of my data can be seen below:

```
{"Username": "bkpn1412", "DOB": "31.07.1983", "State": "Oregon", "Reviewed": ["cea76118f6a9110a893de2b7654319c0"]}
{"Username": "gqjs4414", "DOB": "27.07.1998", "State": "Massachusetts", "Reviewed": ["fa04fe6c0dd5189f54fe600838da43d3"]}
{"Username": "eehe1434", "DOB": "08.08.1950", "State": "Idaho", "Reviewed": []}
{"Username": "hkxj1334", "DOB": "03.08.1969", "State": "Florida", "Reviewed": ["f129b1803f447c2b1ce43508fb822810", "3b0c9bc0be65a3461893488314236116"]}
{"Username": "jjbd1412", "DOB": "26.07.2001", "State": "Georgia", "Reviewed": []}
```

my current code:

```
#converting list to string using list comprehension
pdict = ' '.join([str(item) for item in products_list]) 
print(type(pdict))

rdict = ' '.join([str(item) for item in reviewers_list]) 
print(type(rdict))

#converting string to list of string
plist  = pdict.split(',')
rlist = rdict.split(',')
print(type(plist))
print(type(rlist))

#list of string to dict
products_dicts = {}
for item in plist:
    t = products_dicts
    for part in item.split(':'):
        t = t.setdefault(part, {})
print(type(products_dicts))

reviewers_dicts = {}
for item in rlist:
    t = reviewers_dicts
    for part in item.split(':'):
        t = t.setdefault(part, {})
print(type(reviewers_dicts))
```

I've tried using different delimiters but it hasn't worked, how exactly would I get around this issue (preferably without having to go through a large data set removing all unneeded commas manually).

Expected output should be similar to this:

```
{"Username": "bkpn1412",
"DOB": "31.07.1983",
"State": "Oregon",
"Reviewed": ["cea76118f6a9110a893de2b7654319c0"]}

{"Username": "hkxj1334",
"DOB": "03.08.1969",
"State": "Florida" ,
"Reviewed": ["f129b1803f447c2b1ce43508fb822810", "3b0c9bc0be65a3461893488314236116"]}
```

Comment: Can you please share the expected output

Comment: Have you tried `json.loads`?

Comment: @NirElbaz edited to add the expected output

Comment: the expected output contains invalid syntax

Comment: Does this answer your question? [String to Dictionary in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917006/string-to-dictionary-in-python)

Comment: @Pynchia I get the error ```JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 2 column 2 (char 116)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to solve this problem is to use the built-in function [json.loads](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).

Suppose you have a file with your input data:

***inputdata.txt***

```
{"Username": "bkpn1412", "DOB": "31.07.1983", "State": "Oregon", "Reviewed": ["cea76118f6a9110a893de2b7654319c0"]}
{"Username": "gqjs4414", "DOB": "27.07.1998", "State": "Massachusetts", "Reviewed": ["fa04fe6c0dd5189f54fe600838da43d3"]}
{"Username": "eehe1434", "DOB": "08.08.1950", "State": "Idaho", "Reviewed": []}
{"Username": "hkxj1334", "DOB": "03.08.1969", "State": "Florida", "Reviewed": ["f129b1803f447c2b1ce43508fb822810", "3b0c9bc0be65a3461893488314236116"]}
{"Username": "jjbd1412", "DOB": "26.07.2001", "State": "Georgia", "Reviewed": []}
```

Implementing a parser to this data would be:

```
import json
filename = "inputdata.txt"
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        parsed_data = json.loads(line)
        print(parsed_data)
```

### Working with one line at a time (without load all file in memory).

If you wouldn't like to load all file in the memory for processing, you can change the logic to use the function readline from default package in python.

```
import json
filename = "inputdata.txt"
with open(filename) as f:
    line = f.readline()
    while line:
        parsed_data = json.loads(line)
        print(parsed_data)
        line = f.readline()
```

In this example we are using the context manager "with", for a good explanation why use it, [check here](https://dbader.org/blog/python-context-managers-and-with-statement).
If you do not want to use `with` keywork as a context manager, after done working with file you have to explicitly call `close()` method (in order to avoid resource leak).

If you would like to know more about file handling, you can check in [python official documentation about function open used in files](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=open#open).

Comment: Why read the whole file in memory when the file object itself is iterable, giving you a line per iteration? Just do `for line in f`

Comment: Well, I understand your point. If you want, i can work out a solution with this requirement.

Comment: @Pynchia, just updated answer, check if it work for you. Thanks for pointing out this requirement.