# Load json file with string into pandas dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-science

I have an example json dataset as :

```
['[{"id":"123","product":"dell","date":"2019-01-01","sales":5,"created_at":"2019-01-26 15:00:00"}, {"id":"124","product":"apple","date":"2019-01-02","sales":7,"created_at":"2019-01-27 15:00:00"}]']
```

I would like to create a pandas dataframe from this json data but when i use the json_normalize method i get AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'.

The expected output should be like this:

```
id   product  date        sales   created_at
123.  dell.   2019-01-01.  5.     2019-01-26 15:00:00
124.  apple.  2019-01-02.  7.     2019-01-27 15:00:00
```

Comment: `pd.read_json(yourlist[0])` ? if that is a list

Comment: "... an example json dataset as ..." - well, just how did you get that dataset? Perhaps you just loaded it in incorrectly?

Comment: i tried the list[0] but doesnt work since the result is a type string.

Comment: Convert your string to a python object using json.loads and then load it into df https://stackoverflow.com/a/4917044/5125264

Comment: i tried that, thats when i get the output which is a list of string.

Comment: What is the type you want?

Comment: `which is a list of string` - do it again `json.loads(list_of_string[0]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> thats when i get the output which is a list of string

If the result of json.load... is like

```
a = ['[{"id":"123","product":"dell","date":"2019-01-01","sales":5,"created_at":"2019-01-26 15:00:00"}, {"id":"124","product":"apple","date":"2019-01-02","sales":7,"created_at":"2019-01-27 15:00:00"}]']
```

Then do it again...

```
>>> b = json.loads(a[0])
>>> b
[{'id': '123', 'product': 'dell', 'date': '2019-01-01', 'sales': 5, 'created_at': '2019-01-26 15:00:00'}, {'id': '124', 'product': 'apple', 'date': '2019-01-02', 'sales': 7, 'created_at': '2019-01-27 15:00:00'}]
>>> pd.DataFrame(b)
    id product        date  sales           created_at
0  123    dell  2019-01-01      5  2019-01-26 15:00:00
1  124   apple  2019-01-02      7  2019-01-27 15:00:00
>>>
```

---

Unfortunately you will not have the luxury of knowing in advance that you need to do this. You would need to inspect the data first. Unless you are lucky enough to have the specifications of the *thing* that is making these jsons.

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
import pandas as pd
x = ['[{"id":"123","product":"dell","date":"2019-01-01","sales":5,"created_at":"2019-01-26 15:00:00"}, {"id":"124","product":"apple","date":"2019-01-02","sales":7,"created_at":"2019-01-27 15:00:00"}]']
# Take 0th element of list
x = x[0]
info = json.loads(x)
df = pd.json_normalize(info)
df
```